# How to import data from Excel to SSIS by query in Wizard?

Tags: excel, import, ssis

I'm trying to import data from my Excel file to SSIS by query in Wizard but it keeps failed. The state is: "the statement could not be parsed".

Here are my steps:

1. Open the wizard and choose Data source: Excel and Excel 2016 ver
2. Set SQL Native Client 11.0 as Destination and choose the existing database
3. Choose option: write a query to specify the data to transfer
4. I tried with the simple one:

   ```
   SELECT created_at FROM Sheet1
   ```

   or

   ```
   SELECT [created_at] FROM [Sheet1]
   ```

Comment: try adding a $ to Sheet1 like this Sheet1$. You can even get cute by adding a range like this Sheet1$A2:F  The $ symbolizes a range and not providing a range means look at the whole sheet.

Comment: It does work, thanks a lot